# Access VBA - Handling Null Return in Procedure

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm looking for help on how to recognize a Null value from a query and use that to move forward in my procedure. My code chokes on the Null at the moment. If my query returns a Null, I want the program to move forward. If the query results are not null, I want it to stop and prompt the user. I've tried the IsNull() and IsEmplty() functions but not had any success. I've also tried putting Nz([ ]) around the Count field to force a null to zero, but that hasn't worked either.

```
Private Sub btn_SaveIssue6a_Click()
Dim txt_BondNo As String
Dim prompt07a1 As Integer
Dim prompt7c12 As Integer
Dim txt_SubmNo As String

'This first part is to check and see if there is already a bond issued under this submission no.

Dim DB As Database



Set DB = CurrentDb
Set rs7c = DB.OpenRecordset("SELECT Nz((Count([7_BONDS].[6_BondIssued])),0) AS CountOf6_BondIssued, [7_BONDS].[6_BondIssued], [7_BONDS].[5_SubmNo], [7_BONDS].[5_BondType] " & _
                            "FROM 7_BONDS " & _
                            "GROUP BY [7_BONDS].[6_BondIssued], [7_BONDS].[5_SubmNo], [7_BONDS].[5_BondType] " & _
                            "HAVING ((([7_BONDS].[6_BondIssued])='Issued') AND (([7_BONDS].[5_SubmNo])='" & Me.txt_SubmNo & "') AND (([7_BONDS].[5_BondType])='Bid Bond'));")
                            
                        
If IsNull(rs7c.Fields(0).Value) Then
    
'**************************************************MAIN PROCEDURE*********************************
            
            'THIS IS TO PROMPT THE END-USER WHEN THEY TRY TO ISSUE A BOND
            
                'Launch message box to inquire of the user whether they want to close the form without saving
                prompt07a1 = MsgBox("This will issue the bond in the system. Are you sure you want to issue bond number " & [txt_BondNo] & "?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "Issue Bond")
            
                If prompt07a1 = vbYes Then
                            If DCount("[5_SubmNo]", "7_BONDS", "[5_SubmNo] = txt_SubmNo") = 0 Then
                            DoCmd.OpenQuery ("7a_BidBondSaveISSUED")
                            DoCmd.OpenQuery ("7c_app_BondAmt")
                            Else
                            DoCmd.OpenQuery ("7b_upd_BidBondISSUEDupdate")
                            DoCmd.OpenQuery ("7c_app_BondAmt")
                            End If
                Else
                DoCmd.Close acForm, "MsgBox", acSaveNo
                End If

Else
prompt7c12 = MsgBox("There is already a bid bond issued for this submission.", vbOKOnly, "Duplicate") = vbOK

End If

Set DB = Nothing
Set rs7c = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you mean it returns an empty recordset? Try `IF rs7c.BOF AND rs7c.EOF THEN`  [Recordset.BOF property (DAO)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/recordset-bof-property-dao)

Comment: That worked, thank you!  And I learned something!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A record with NULL value(s) and an empty recordset are two very different things.

After `OpenRecordset`, checking for `.EOF` is needed, if an empty result is possible.

So:

```
Set rs7c = DB.OpenRecordset("...")
If rs7c.EOF then

    ' Ok, nothing found, run main procedure

Else
    prompt7c12 = MsgBox("There is already a bid bond issued for this submission.", vbOKOnly, "Duplicate") = vbOK
End If
```